# Angular 5 / Google Map - "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Tags: angular, google-maps, undefined, markerclusterer

I use Angular 5 with one type : "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.28". This type installs @types/google-maps.

I added script part in "index.html" file to load map.
In my component, I can use google namespace.
This works fine.

However, when I run tests... it fails!
I got "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

I tried so many things... If you have any idea, I take it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

In your test you can use a mock/stub to define `google` on the `window` object as well as any other objects/functions your component is interacting with:

```
window['google'] = {
  maps: {
    Maps: () => {}
  }
};
```

You can then use using Jasmine [Spies](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to intercept calls to a given object and/or function on the `google` such as `maps` to return custom values or anything else you'd need to test your component.

```
const spy = spyOn(window['google']['maps'], 'Maps').and.returnValue({});
```

The reason bracket notation is being used to please the TypeScript compiler. With dot notation you'd see an error such as `Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Window'`.

Hopefully that helps as least resolve the undefined error you are seeing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Alexander!

You bring me a real clue!

After your post, I looked deeper into angular google mock. 
I finally found this : [GoogleMock](https://github.com/sttts/google-maps-mock/blob/master/google-maps-mock.js). 
I then adjusted it and it works.

Thanks !

Comment: For anyone still struggling with this, make sure you include the GoogleMock js file in the script array under test in your angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",   
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",                       
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["src/app/mock/GoogleMock.js"],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).