# Mock Google Maps object with typescript definitions

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular component that depends on the `google.maps.Map` class. It looks like this:

```
export class MapViewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    public mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions;

    public map: google.maps.Map;

    @ViewChild("map", { static: true })
    mapDomNode: ElementRef;

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapDomNode.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);
    }
}
```

I installed Google Maps type definitions according to [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript):

```
npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

Now I need to create unit tests for my component and try to use the approach from the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267659/533711) (I use Karma for testing):

```
window['google'] = {
    maps: {
        Map: () => ({})
    }
};
const spy = spyOn(window['google']['maps'], 'Maps').and.returnValue({});
```

I get the error:

```
Type '() => {}' is not assignable to type 'typeof Map'.
  Type '() => {}' provides no match for the signature 'new (mapDiv: Element, opts?: MapOptions): Map'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(3223, 9): The expected type comes from property 'Map' which is declared here on type 'typeof maps'
```

I tried to use different variations, like `Map: () => { return {} as google.maps.Map }` and many other things but TypeScript always shows type errors.

How can I use any object instead of the `google.maps.Map` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding `any` to the end of the mock object:

```
googleMaps = jasmine.createSpyObj('Maps', ['setCenter', 'setZoom', 'setOptions']);

function Map() {
    return googleMaps;
}

window['google'] = {
    maps: {
        Map: Map,
        ...
    }
} as any; // <---
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the `{}` like so:

```
const spy = spyOn(window['google']['maps'], 'Maps').and.returnValue({} as Map);
```

And if that doesn't work, you can use `any`:

```
const spy = spyOn(window['google']['maps'], 'Maps').and.returnValue({} as any);
```

Edit
Try:

```
window['google'] = {
    maps: {
        Map: () => ({}) as any,
    }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. The error is on this line: `Map: () => ({})`.

Comment: Try my edit, if that doesn't work, I am not sure then.